# changing date format to word in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable ($date) holding the start date of an event which is in this format:

```
 2012-11-20 (YYYY-M-D)
```

And I have another variable ($duration) holding a number e.g '3' which is number of days or duration of the event. How can i increment the day in the date variable by the duration variable and then display the event date in this format

```
 20th - 23th November
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('F d Y');
```

[See php date() for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

If you have `2012-11-20` in a variable, you can do this:

```
$date = '2012-11-20';
echo date('F d Y', strtotime($date));
//=> November 20 2012
```

Two things to consider:

1. If you don't have control over the date, you might want to take extra precaution using [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). If you give `strtotime()` an invalid date string, it will return `false`
2. Every call to a date/time function will generate a `E_NOTICE` if the time zone is not valid, and/or a `E_STRICT` or `E_WARNING` message if using the system settings or the `TZ` environment variable. See also [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

A more robust solution:

```
// date input
$date = '2012-11-20';

// set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

// validate date
if ( ($time=strtotime($date)) === false ) {
    throw new Exception("invalid date given: {$date}");
}

// output
echo date('F d Y', $time);
```

---

### EDIT

You updated your question asking how to get a date range. For this, I'd recommend the following:

```
// input
$date = '2012-11-20';
$duration = 3;

// set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

// parse date
try {

    // init range
    $start = new DateTime($date);
    $end = clone $start;

    // modify end date based on $duration
    $end->modify(sprintf("+%d days", $duration));
    
    // output range
    echo $start->format('jS') . ' - ' . $end->format('jS F Y');

    //=> 20th - 23rd November 2012

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm sorry the question i posted initially was incomplete...Pls kindly look through the question again...Thanks.

Comment: @Sms, I added an edit based on your updated question. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it worked but the event date is not constant rather it's dynamic..So, I noticed for event date like this '2012-12-03' it will output or print it out like this '03rd - 08th December 2012'...Do you notice the zero before the date '03rd' and '08th'...I would really appreciate if you could help strip off the zero when displaying the date...Thanks so much for your help..

Comment: @sms, this is very clearly documented in the [date() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I updated the format string to use `j` instead of `d` to output the day number without the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

First, [convert your date into a timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date_str = "2012-11-20";
$timestamp = strtotime($date_str);
```

Then [convert the timestamp into the format you require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$formatted_date = date('F d Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: You want `'F d Y'` as the format string. `'F m Y'` will show "Novermber 11 2012" in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm sorry the question i posted initially was incomplete...Pls kindly look through the question again...Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @macek, edited the date string. Your updated answer covers the OP's edits, so I'll leave it.